# Javascript using constructor.prototype to visit superclass member fails?

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype, undefined, superclass

I've got a small code snippet:

```
function father(){
    this.id=10
}
function child(){}
console.log(child.prototype.constructor);//[Function: child]
child.prototype=new father();
//child.prototype.constructor = child; // key line
var son=new child();
console.log(child.prototype.constructor);//[Function: father]
console.log(son.constructor.prototype.id);//undefined.
```

As the code indicates, I used prototype chain to create "son" object. 
But The last line prints

```
"undefined".
```

This is weird to me. child.prototype.constructor is [Function: father], and "id" is actually a property of "father" why it prints undefined?

If I uncomment the keyline of

```
    child.prototype.constructor = child; // key line
```

Then it prints "10" as I expected. The difference of having the key line or not, for me, is child.prototype.constructor is either 'child' or 'father'. But 'id' is a father property, why need to set key line in my code?

Thanks.

Comment: `id` is neither a property of `father` nor of `father.prototype`. It's a property of `father` instances!

Comment: i tried to answer it with some bad images :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step 1)

```
function father(){
    this.id=10
}
function child(){}
```

Looks like

[image]

and this case  when do `console.log(child.prototype.constructor);//[Function: child]` it works as you expected

STEP 2)  `child.prototype=new father();`

[image]

Now you see here, original `child.prototype` is lost and `child.prototype.constructor`  is also lost.  you created an object from `father` and used that object as `child.prototype`

STEP 3) `var son=new child();`

[image]

Now  `console.log(child.prototype.constructor);//[Function: father]`   is straight forward to understand.

How do we get there ? `son.__proto__.__proto__.constructor`.

Now, considering the same image

`console.log(son.constructor.prototype.id);//undefined.`   What happens here ?    `son.constructor`  is nothing but `father` and `son.constructor.prototype`  is nothing but `father.prototype` , which does not have a property names  `id`.

NOTE:
`son.constructor`  is `son.__proto__.__proto__.constructor`

Now  what happens you uncomment  `child.prototype.constructor = child;` ?

You are adding a `constructor` property to `child.prototype`  and in that case when you say `son.constructor`  this means `child`   and `son.constructor.prototype`  is nothing but `child.prototype` , which does have a property names  `id`  and value is 10.

Sorry for all images  and bad explanation!!

Comment: I just couldn't find a way of putting it into words.  Well done.

Comment: Nice illustration. Wish that their size had not been scaled down and focus  not blurred.

Comment: Well, well, well, this is one of the best answers I got since my stackoverflow journey. Well done Oxi and thanks a lot for your explanations! Votes!

Comment: @Troskyvs : happy i could help :)

Answer (score -1):

Actually you are overwriting the prototype object of child function() so the internal **proto** link is getting lost.

```
function father(){
    this.id=10
}
function child(){}
console.log(child.prototype.constructor);//[Function: child]
child.prototype=new father();
child.__proto__ = father;
var son=new child();
console.log(child.prototype.constructor);//[Function: father]
console.log(son.id);//10
```

Comment: a) don't use `__proto__` b) it doesn't work c) there is no link that is lost

Comment: Then how to explain my question? Thanks.

Comment: __proto__ shouldn't ever be used directly. The __proto__ is a non-standard property, provided by Firefox/Chrome. In other browsers the property still exists internally, but it is hidden.